# How to implement highlight and transition effect for nodes in D3js force directed graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I am trying to implement Higlight effect on nodes in D3 js force directed graph.

I am facing the below issues while doing so.

Highlight effect:
    a. On mouse hover of the selected node, I am changing the color of its neighboring nodes . But the color of other nodes should not get changed(In my case, Its turning red and not sure how to fix it)     How to fix this ?.
    b. On mouse hover of the selected node, I would like to add the transition effect as well for all interconnected nodes by increasing radius of it.
       Also other nodes should get faded out, Is that possible ?

Please refer the working js fiddle for reference:
    [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekhegde99/0cy31xg7/327/)

```
var nodeElements =  g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 40)
.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); })
  .attr("stroke", "#fff")
  .attr('stroke-width', 21)
  .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id })
      .on('mouseover', selectNode)
      .on('mouseout', releaseNode)
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));

function releaseNode() {
   nodeElements.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id)
   })
}

function selectNode(selectedNode) {
  var neighbors = getNeighbors(selectedNode)
  nodeElements.attr('fill', function(node) {
    return getNodeColor(node, neighbors)
  })
}

function getNeighbors(node) {
  return graph.links.reduce(function(neighbors, link) {
    if (link.target.id === node.id) {
      neighbors.push(link.source.id)
    } else if (link.source.id === node.id) {
      neighbors.push(link.target.id)
    }
    return neighbors
  }, [node.id])
}

function getNodeColor(node, neighbors) {
  // If is neighbor
  if (Array.isArray(neighbors) && neighbors.indexOf(node.id) > -1) {
    return 'rgba(251, 130, 30, 1)'
    // return node.level === 1 ? '#9C4A9C' : 'rgba(251, 130, 30, 1)'
  } else {
    return 'red';
  }
  //return node.level === 0 ? '#91007B' : '#D8ABD8'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To not change the colors of the other nodes when you mouseover, you will have to change the `getNodeColor` function below:

   ```
   function getNodeColor(node, neighbors) {
     // If is neighbor
     if ( neighbors.indexOf(node.id) > -1) {
       return 'rgba(251, 130, 30, 1)'
     } 
     else {
           return color(node.id);
     }
   }
   ```
2. In order to enlarge nodes you will have to call another function `getNodeRadius` in the `selectNode` function which gets called `on('mouseover', selectNode);`

   ```
   function selectNode(selectedNode) {
     var neighbors = getNeighbors(selectedNode)
     nodeElements.transition()
           .duration(500)
           .attr('fill', function(node) {
               return getNodeColor(node, neighbors)
             })
           .attr('r', function(node) {
             return getNodeRadius(node,neighbors);
           })
   }
   ```

Notice the methods `.transition().duration(500)` indicates to animate to this end state with a duration of 500 ms.

The `getNodeRadius` function needs to be defined as:

```
function getNodeRadius(node, neighbors) {
  // If is neighbor
  if ( neighbors.indexOf(node.id) > -1) {
    return '60'
  } 
  else {
        return '40'
  }
}
```

Fully working example below:

```js
var graph = {
'nodes':[
{'id':'Material_Definition','group':0},
{'id':'Lot1','group':1},
{'id':'Lot2','group':1},
{'id':'Lot3','group':1},
{'id':'Lot4','group':1},
{'id':'Lot5','group':1},
{'id':'Lot6','group':1},
{'id':'Lot7','group':1},
{'id':'Lot8','group':1},
{'id':'Lot9','group':1},
{'id':'Lot10','group':1},
{'id':'Lot11','group':1},
{'id':'Lot12','group':1},
{'id':'Lot13','group':1},
{'id':'Lot14','group':1},
{'id':'Lot15','group':1},
{'id':'Lot16','group':1},
{'id':'Lot17','group':1},
{'id':'Lot18','group':1},
{'id':'Lot19','group':1},
{'id':'Lot20','group':1},
{'id':'SubLot1_Lot1','group':2},
{'id':'SubLot2_Lot1','group':2},
{'id':'SubLot3_Lot1','group':2},
{'id':'SubLot4_Lot1','group':2},
{'id':'SubLot5_Lot1','group':2},
{'id':'SubLot6_Lot1','group':2},
{'id':'SubLot1_Lot2','group':2},
{'id':'SubLot2_Lot2','group':2},
{'id':'SubLot3_Lot2','group':2},
{'id':'SubLot4_Lot2','group':2},
{'id':'SubLot5_Lot2','group':2},
{'id':'SubLot6_Lot2','group':2}],
'links':[
/* Material Definition linked to Lots */
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot1','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot2','value':8,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot3','value':10,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot3','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot4','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot5','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot6','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot7','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot8','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot9','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot10','value':8,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot11','value':10,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot12','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot13','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot14','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot15','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot16','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot17','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot18','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot19','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Material_Definition','target':'Lot20','value':1,'type':'A'},

/* Lot1 is linked to Sublots */
{'source':'Lot1','target':'SubLot1_Lot1','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot1','target':'SubLot2_Lot1','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot1','target':'SubLot3_Lot1','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot1','target':'SubLot4_Lot1','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot1','target':'SubLot5_Lot1','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot1','target':'SubLot6_Lot1','value':1,'type':'A'},

/* Lot2 is linked to Sublots */
{'source':'Lot2','target':'SubLot1_Lot2','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot2','target':'SubLot2_Lot2','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot2','target':'SubLot3_Lot2','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot2','target':'SubLot4_Lot2','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot2','target':'SubLot5_Lot2','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot2','target':'SubLot6_Lot2','value':1,'type':'A'},

/* Interconnected Lots */
{'source':'Lot10','target':'Lot18','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot10','target':'Lot19','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot10','target':'Lot20','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot7','target':'Lot8','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot7','target':'Lot9','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot7','target':'Lot10','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot12','target':'Lot4','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot12','target':'Lot3','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot12','target':'Lot2','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot16','target':'Lot1','value':1,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot16','target':'Lot9','value':2,'type':'A'},
{'source':'Lot16','target':'Lot12','value':1,'type':'A'}
]};


var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var zoom_handler = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoom_actions);

// zoom_handler(svg);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(300).id(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  }))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-300))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "everything");

svg.call(zoom_handler)
  .call(zoom_handler.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(200, 150).scale(0.2));


var linkElements = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .style("stroke-width",5.5)
  .style("stroke",'black');

var nodeElements =  g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 40)
  .attr('class', 'nodecircles')
.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); })
  .attr("stroke", "#fff")
  .attr('stroke-width', 21)
  .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id })
      .on('mouseover', selectNode)
      .on('mouseout', releaseNode)
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));
    
function releaseNode(d) {
   nodeElements.transition().duration(500)
   .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id)
   })
   .attr('r', 40);
}
  
var textElements = g.append("g")    // use g.append instead of svg.append to enable zoom
  .attr("class", "texts")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("text")
  .text(function(node) {
    return node.id
  })
  .attr("font-size", 55)
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("style", "font-weight:bold; text-stroke: 1px #fff;")
  .attr("dx", 0)
  .attr("dy", 20)

function ticked() {
  linkElements
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
  nodeElements
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .each(d => { d3.select('#t_' + d.id).attr('x', d.x + 10).attr('y', d.y + 3); });
    textElements
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return d.y
    });
    
}

simulation
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .on("tick", ticked);

simulation.force("link")
  .links(graph.links);


function zoom_actions() {
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

function selectNode(selectedNode) {
  var neighbors = getNeighbors(selectedNode)
  nodeElements.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr('fill', function(node) {
    return getNodeColor(node, neighbors)
  })
    .attr('r', function(node) {
    return getNodeRadius(node,neighbors);
  })
}

function getNeighbors(node) {
  return graph.links.reduce(function(neighbors, link) {
    if (link.target.id === node.id) {
      neighbors.push(link.source.id)
    } else if (link.source.id === node.id) {
      neighbors.push(link.target.id)
    }
    return neighbors
  }, [node.id])
}

function getNodeColor(node, neighbors) {
  // If is neighbor
  if ( neighbors.indexOf(node.id) > -1) {
    return 'rgba(251, 130, 30, 1)'
  } 
  else {
  return color(node.id);
  }
}

function getNodeRadius(node, neighbors) {
  // If is neighbor
  if ( neighbors.indexOf(node.id) > -1) {
    return '60'
  } 
  else {
  return '40'
  }
}
```

```css
   .links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">


</html>

<svg width="798" height="400"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```